Reconciling Process Philosophy w/ Absolute Idealism
I'm currently reading through Nicholas Rescher's Process Philosophy: A Survey of Basic Issues and early in it, he says:

The work of actually developing the process doctrine to the point where it can be compared with other major philosophical projects like materialism or absolute idealism still remains to be done.

I'd not yet heard of absolute idealism so I do a quick internet search and find out that (if I can be so clumsy in summary) essentially the idea is that the entire universe is a single mind that is working towards self realization.
I quickly remembered an earlier part of the survey of process philosophy where Rescher overviews philosophy of mind within a process philosophy metaphysics. The idea (again, summary) is that the experience of a mind arises from a process (as do all things in process philosophy) and according to my additional research some process-minded philosophers think this can even lead to panexperientialism or the idea that all being has mind in some capacity just as we humans do (although likely very different for very different things).
If process is the most fundamental ontological entity and necessarily gives rise to mind in the panexperientialist way, then would it be valid operation to try to cheat process philosophy into a "major philosophical project" by saying that this whole being of the universe gives rise to a mind, namely, the one referenced in absolute idealism? What kind of issues might you run into while doing that and have I interpreted either discipline in an egregious way?
I ran these thoughts through a chatbot to try to pick out any obvious issues and the objection it gave me was that process philosophers tend to believe in the need for process to continue forever whereas absolute idealists believe that there's a self realization goal that must be met in some end state.  I don't know enough about either discipline at this stage to speak definitively about any of this, but it feels like at the very least you can fit the entire act of self-realization in absolute idealism into the definition of a process and at worst you have to come up with an idea for how the process ends.  Or maybe you can reference the mathematical concept of limits where there is both an ongoing "approach" and a fixed "goal" that is never actually reached.

"Process philosophy" is a vague label and classical absolute idealism (Hegel's especially) already was a variant of "process philosophy" (speculative process metaphysics), or at least a precursor to it. Having/not having 'final goal' is not particularly central to the process conception, it is a tangential metaphysical preference. See SEP's historical overview for comparisons of absolute idealism with other variants of process metaphysics.

Ah so Rescher is misleading me?

He just uses the label more narrowly, with more recent and more analytic variants of it in mind. SEP discusses their distinctive features.

Contemporary "process philosophy" often refers to Whitehead's school of thought ("Process and Reality"). It can, in some way, be viewed as a major modification of an absolute idealistic framework (in my personal opinion, mainly Schellingian rather than Hegelian), but that might hinder a bit from the understanding of both philosophies. This is actually being done by modern philosophers like Matthew Segal and most of the Center for Process Studies people (Andrew Davis, John Cobb Jr., David Ray Griffin). But as stated, both philosophies contain more nuances.

BTW iirc Whitehead himself offers a sort of absolute idealistic version in the last few chapters of Process and Reality (a bit more "naturalized" than the 18-19th century versions).

Oh and BTW 2: there's an interesting talk between Matthew Segall and Bernardo Katsrup that represents almost exactly this discussion.

The distinction here is between something that exists in principle and something that exists in potential. In other words, if we are given an acorn, there are two possible ways of looking at it:

There is a theoretical, idealized oak tree that the acorn strives (and to some extent always fails) to achieve, or…
there is a set of potentials extant within the acorn that are developed over time, without any specific, pre-ordained goal.

What we're wrestling with is the seeming paradox that things can grow and change over time yet still maintain a consistent identity. The first position asserts that identity is pre-given. This covers the continuity of identity over time, but creates some metaphysical quandaries about what these 'theoretical, idealized' templates are and where they might exist, and what the rational for change might be. The second position holds that identity is merely a matter of process continuity: that a thing is identified as itself, no matter how it changes, because the changes are smooth and continuous. This accounts for change well, but has a harder time explaining why (say) as acorn always develops into an oak, and not sometimes into an elm, or a carrot, or a horse.
If we take this to a universal level, we end up with the difference between brahman and dao. Brahman is universal consciousness: the consciousness of the universe seeking to know itself through the consciousness of its elements. Dao is pure process: the universe moving through its ineffable patterns without conscious effort. They are largely incommensurate worldviews; honestly, worldviews split over the question of whether identity matters at all. It's not something that will be easily rectified.

This is maybe what I'm failing to understand: "without any specific, pre-ordained goal".  What is inherent to process philosophy that a process cannot have or perhaps imply a goal?  Can we not give an acorn continuous change but say that it changes "oakly" as compared to a carrot seed which changes "carrotly"?

A goal is only given in hindsight (?) "It ain't over till it's over" as Yogi Berra said.

I'm sorry @mudskipper I don't understand the point (or was it just color commentary?)

Np - Of course you can say that the acorn changes "oakly", but then it seems you're reverting back to goals as fixed given (ideal principle). There is nothing wrong with that as such, except that it might make you forget that the actual process may veer "off course".  From a daoist "point of view" you can only say something like: "Everything is just so" or rather "Every happening happens just so". (Don't know if this makes sense.) The poetic meme (for the self) is an empty boat drifting aimlessly over the water.

Is it a fundamental feature of process philosophy to have this instantaneous nature? Does processing towards a fixed goal without the capacity for change somehow invalidate the rest of the metaphysics? Is process+determinism an incompatibility?

@MattHauff: If we broaden the picture a little and think in evolutionary terms, the genome of oaks will change so that what then passes for an acorn will not produce what now passes for an oak. Our distant ancestors were not human beings, and our distant descendants will likely not be human beings either (and will likely think of us the way we think of apes). So, when hominids first roamed the plains of Africa, was the goal to become us, to become something past us, to become one with the universe itself…? Or was it merely a process where forms slowly morph in tandem with thier environment?

@MattHauff: Or maybe better put… achieving a goal-state involves a process, but a process doesn't need to have an intention or goal. The ocean isn't trying to erode the shore, but it does so regardless. It isn't necessarily a mistake to think there might be a goal-state, but it is usually a mistake to believe we know what that goal-state is.

@Ted Wrigley does an absolute idealist think they know what the end goal of the universal mind is? What about the changing definition of oak or human is unique to process philosophy instead of absolute idealism? I feel like potentially the metaphor has gotten lost here because the oak tree is supposed to be the fully self realized universe mind, correct? That's not going to change in absolute idealism and a process can work towards it in perpetuity and leverage that for an identity just as much as the mind working towards it could.

@MattHauff: Think of Platonic idealism or Abrahamic theology. In both cases 'human' is an ideal — one a Platonic form, the other an image of God — towards which individual humans are meant to strive. The thought that 'human' might eventually change to something different (much less superior) is antithetical to the concept of such an ideal. I won't say it's impossible, but it is difficult to conceptualize something which is both ideal (ostensibly perfect) and malleable (subject to change).

I think my point is: why can't something be ideally malleable? If we're being process philosophers, don't we really care about the nature of something's process rather than any particular state that is given rise to by that process?

@MattHauff: This is more than I can do justice to in comments, but to oversimplify: an ideal is the template for a category. When I say the word 'gem' I invoke the category of things that are 'gem-like'; that category has standards for inclusion, and (ostensibly) there is an absolute set of standards that lets us distinguish gems from non-gems. That's the ideal of a gem. If that ideal is malleable, then we can no longer distinguish gems from non-gems, and the category collapses.

@MattHauff: on the other hand, if we develop categories procedurally (as an ongoing process) then what constitutes 'gem' might change over time: what we call 'gems' might be entirely different from people a thousand years from now. There's no fixed standard, and so there's no ideal in any credible sense.

@MattHauff: The only way around this, I think, is to use ineffable ideals: ideals that cannot be expressed. That way we can have fixed ideals and still justify change as a constant cycling or drift around that which can never be perfectly expressed. A bit like non-linear dynamic systems…
